# How to extends a class that received parameters with Guice dependency injection

Tags: scala, guice

I have a class that is defined as:

```
class CalloutReaderService @Inject()(configuration: Configuration, sparkSession: SparkSession, domainUtils: DomainUtils, udfDefinitions: UdfDefinitions,
                                 dwhSiteInstanceReader: DwhSiteInstanceReader)
extends Serializable {
```

and I would like to create a new class that inherents from the above:

```
   class CalloutReaderServiceTest extends CalloutReaderService
```

What is the correct syntax when using Guice Dependency Injection?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You still need to inject every dependency into the constructor (of your subclass):

```
class CalloutReaderServiceTest @Inject() (
  configuration: Configuration, 
  sparkSession: SparkSession, 
  domainUtils: DomainUtils,
  udfDefinitions: UdfDefinitions,
  dwhSiteInstanceReader: DwhSiteInstanceReader) 
  extends CalloutReaderService (
  configuration,
  sparkSession,
  domainUtils,
  udfDefinitions,
  dwhSiteInstanceReader)
```

However, do you really need to make a subclass? Especially with this name, it sounds like you just want to instantiate the "normal" `CalloutReaderService` with a set of dependencies appropriate for testing.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I could run my test if I would dependencies for testing for CalloutReaderService. can you please share an example, or link to an appropriate guide. thanks!